Sum of $2023$ numbers in $2022$nd power can be shown in at least $100$ different ways.
Show that there exists at least one positive integer that can be shown as sum of $2023$ numbers' $2022$nd power in at least $100$ different ways.(Permutations do not count as different ways.)
I tried to name the sum with $N$ and numbers with $a_1,\ldots,a_{2023}$ so, we have $\sqrt[2023]{\frac{N}{2023}}\geq a_i$. Then if we denote the number of possible combinations with $k$.The inequality we wanna find is $k\geq \frac{\sqrt[2023]\frac{N}{2023}}{2023!}\geq \text{something} \geq 100N$.We must use $2022$ somewhere here, but I'm stuck from here, this is an enumeration question, so we must find a bound and show that we'll pass it somewhere, then question ends. But how?

Is $a_i=0$ allowed?

Where is the Q from ?

@JoshuaWang No,all the numbers are positive integers

@Prem No idea,just from a handout

Looks an Olympiad question...

The Q is highly vague

Let $x$ be an arbitary positive integer.
There are $x$ $2022$-th powers from $1$ to $x^{2022}$.
There are $x^{2023}$ distinct sequences of $2023$ $2022$-th powers from $1$ to $x^{2022}$.
Each sequence has sum from $1$ to $2023x^{2022}$ inclusive, so there are at most $2023x^{2022}$ possible sums.
So there is a positive integer from $1$ to $2023x^{2022}$ inclusive that can be written as the sum of a sequence of $2023$ $2022$-th powers in at least $\left\lceil\frac{x^{2023}}{2023x^{2022}}\right\rceil$ ways if permutations of the same sequence are different.
Each multiset $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{2023}\}$ is represented by at most $2023!$ distinct sequences.
So there is a positive integer from $1$ to $2023x^{2022}$ inclusive that can be written as the sum of a sequence of $2023$ $2022$-th powers in at least $\left\lceil\frac{\left\lceil\frac{x^{2023}}{2023x^{2022}}\right\rceil}{2023!}\right\rceil$ ways if permutations of the same sequence are considered the same.
For sufficiently large $x$, $\left\lceil\frac{\left\lceil\frac{x^{2023}}{2023x^{2022}}\right\rceil}{2023!}\right\rceil\ge100$ so there is a positive integer that can be written as the sum of a sequence of $2023$ $2022$-th powers in at least $100$ ways if permutations of the same sequence are considered the same.
